# Boundary for comment box

Tags: java, graphics, comments

In my java application, I need to create a comment box for the users to add comments. Moreover, I need to provide the user with the provision for resizing and dragging the comment box. For this, I need to show a boundary around the comment box as in the case of comment box in Microsoft Excel which I have shown below:

[image]

I dont need the circles shown on the boundary for resizing because I will be using a triangle kind of a thing on the bottom-right of the box. But I need the dotted area.

How do I create it for my application in java? Any good thoughts?

---

Currently I am in an analysis phase, just to find good options for this. What we have thought till now is to draw few dotted lines around the box to give the impression.

Answer (score 1):

I would perhaps look at using [JXLayer](https://jxlayer.dev.java.net/) for this.  It looks like what you're trying to do here is paint some context outside the of component's bounds.  This is the kind of thing JXLayer excels at.

Comment: +1 for JXLayer; and a shameless plug for example - my still in WIP project at http://code.google.com/p/jchronos/ - on the homepage, you can see there is a rounded form with shadow around it; and thanks to Romain Guy(www.curious-creature.org)

Answer (score 0):

This can be a little bit tricky. When you need semitransparent border it will be pain. If not, it is easy. Just use popup with appropriate components and mouse listener to listen on mouse events occurred over active borders.